# MySQL concat() not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

In my database table, I have a field where I am storing userid's as comma separated values like 1,2,3 etc. Each user id's are added to the field through updation at a certain point. So if field contain value 1, then I want to append new userid as `,2` on next updation so that all values will be separated by comma.

I am using the following mysql for it:

```
"UPDATE videorating 
    SET total_votes='".$added."', 
        total_value='".$sum."', 
        userid=CONCAT(userid,',$userid'), 
        used_ips='".$insertip."' 
        WHERE videoid='$id_sent'";
```

Here `$userid` will contain the userid. But this is not working properly. The field is not getting updated. What is wrong with this query.

Can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Field is not getting updated at all or being updated incorrectly? and what about other fields?

Comment: You have a design problem. You shouldn't store multiple values in one column. That's what relational tables are for.

Comment: try this: `userid=CONCAT(userid,',',$userid)`

Comment: please confirm, userid field should not be on `int`, it should be of `varchar`

Comment: thanks all..got it..the problem was the datatype of the field was int..now I changed it to varchar

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your `userid` column really is `varchar` or not? If it is `varchar` (or some other text based) then your code should work. This is the same as your but with too many quotes:

```
UPDATE videorating
SET total_votes='$added',
    total_value='$sum', 
    userid=CONCAT(userid,',$userid'),
    used_ips='$insertip'
WHERE videoid='$id_sent'";
```

If it in fact is an `int` you cannot do it like this and you need to rethink what you want to archieve.